# Drols exception Unable to load dialect 'mvel'

Tags: drools, mvel

I'm trying to start a rather trivial example

```java
KieContainer kieContainer = KieServices.Factory.get().getKieClasspathContainer();
StatelessKieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newStatelessKieSession("MyStatelessValidationStep");
```

and at the 2nd line I get an error `NullPointerException` which seems to be caused by the exception `Unable to load dialect 'mvel'`.
It happens with the latest **Drools** version **7.57.0.Final** but works OK with e.g. **7.39.0.Final**. I've listed the docs trying to find out what changed between those versions, but couldn't find the answer. So, is this a bug or I'm missing something new in my source code?

p.s.

Here is a list of the libraries I'm using:

```
ext {
    drools_version = '7.57.0.Final'
    slf4j_version = '1.7.32'
    mvel_version = '2.4.12.Final'
    junit_version = '5.6.0'
}
```

@"Roddy of the Frozen Peas", here are the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-core
    implementation group: 'org.drools', name: 'drools-core', version: "$drools_version"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-compiler
    implementation group: 'org.drools', name: 'drools-compiler', version: "$drools_version"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kie/kie-api
    compileOnly group: 'org.kie', name: 'kie-api', version: "$drools_version"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kie/kie-internal
    implementation group: 'org.kie', name: 'kie-internal', version: "$drools_version"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: "$slf4j_version"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-nop', version: "$slf4j_version"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mvel/mvel2
    implementation group: 'org.mvel', name: 'mvel2', version: "$mvel_version"

    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junit_version"
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
}
```

Note that if I replace `compileOnly` with `implementation` for the `kie-api`, nothing changes in the final result - I still get `NPE`.

Comment: Those appear to be properties / versions. What are the actual dependencies you're using? drools-core? what? I'm especially concerned because you seem to be explicitly pulling in a mvel library.

Comment: OK, I edited the first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `7.45.0.Final` MVEL evaluation has been moved to a separated module called `drools-mvel`, [see the release notes](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.57.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_descope_of_mvel_and_asm_based_features). Please add that module as well or use instead the aggregator module `drools-engine-classic`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I will follow the Drools team recommendations and chose `drools-engine-classic`.